# Can preorder and postorder traversals be used on any type of trees?

Tags: data-structures

I could not find an answer to the question directly by google.

I think this question is rather simple but I am not really sure about it.

Any advice is welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, yea. But you need to define formally what a "type of tree" could be. General trees, are described by the mathematical notion of a [tree graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). Given some ordering on the nodes of the tree, and some definition of which node is the root of the tree, you can perform the "pre-order" and "post-order" traversals.

The algorithms that computes them are also very similar to the ones you are probably familiar with, with the small change that you need to iterate all children instead of just traversing on the two children (since the number of children isn't restricted here).

However, the in-order is not defined properly for trees without also defining a notion of what children are "to the left" of the root and what children are "to the right" of the root. When you give a formal definition to this idea as well, you can perform the in-order traversal as well.

Comment: Thanks, I added the statement that this is required in order to determine the pre and post orders.

Comment: Instead of "an odd number of children" or even number of children, left children and right children might be clearer.

Comment: There is no general "left" or "right" children in a tree-graph

Comment: That is exactly the point why an answer for this question should mention them.

Comment: But we can't say that there are left or right children because the number of children is odd. lets say we have $5$ children: $a,b,c,d,e$. Then we know that $a,b$ are to the "left" and $d,e$ are to the "right", but the problem arises with $c$ which isn't any one of those.

Comment: How do we know that "$a,b$ are to the 'left'"? It is possible that "$a,b,c,d$" are to the left and only "$e$" is to the right. For example, suppose we have a rooted tree where important children are put to the left of the parent. (Basically, give a natural meaning of "to the left" and "to the right").

Comment: I totally agree. I gave the definition using the (most) natural meaning (in my opinion) of "to the left" and "to the right". Maybe I should clarify this in the answer.

Comment: I would like to believe that the most natural meaning of "to the left" here is "to the left of its parent". It is rather not "on the left side of the children". (Then you could argue that the parent will be most likely situated in the middle. Well, maybe. Then, again, check my example above.)